Calculate weighted average by date
I'm new to R and having some difficulty aggregating by date. I have time-series data with multiple price and quantity entries per date. The actual data is more complex, but it looks something like this:
price<-c(1.50,3,1.50,3,3,2.90,3)
quantity<-c(10,5,10,5,5,5,5)
date<-c('01/09/21','01/09/21','01/16/21','01/16/21','01/23/21','01/30/21','01/30/21')
df<-data.frame(date,price,quantity)




date
price
quantity




01/09/21
1.5
10


01/09/21
3
5


01/16/21
1.5
10


01/16/21
3
5


01/23/21
3
5


01/30/21
2.9
5


01/30/21
3
5



I'd like to create a new data frame with only the four individual dates and a single price value for each. To do so, I'm trying to calculate the weighted average of price on each individual date, similar to the example below:



date
price_weighted




01/09/21
2


01/16/21
2


01/23/21
3


01/30/21
2.95



I've tried using price_weighted<-aggregate(price~date,df,weighted.mean), which returns something similar to what I want, but for some reason it's calculating the average price rather than the weighted average. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

You can do this with dplyr by adding up the price times the quantity divided by the total quantity in that day.
library(dplyr)
price<-c(1.50,3,1.50,3,3,2.90,3)
quantity<-c(10,5,10,5,5,5,5)
date<-c('01/09/21','01/09/21','01/16/21','01/16/21','01/23/21','01/30/21','01/30/21')
df<-data.frame(date,price,quantity)

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(wt_mean = sum(price * quantity/sum(quantity)))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   date     wt_mean
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 01/09/21    2   
#> 2 01/16/21    2   
#> 3 01/23/21    3   
#> 4 01/30/21    2.95

You could also do this with by() or tapply() from base R:
by(df, list(df$date), function(x)Hmisc::wtd.mean(x$price, weights=x$quantity))
#> : 01/09/21
#> [1] 2
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> : 01/16/21
#> [1] 2
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> : 01/23/21
#> [1] 3
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> : 01/30/21
#> [1] 2.95

tapply(df, df$date, function(x)Hmisc::wtd.mean(x$price, weights=x$quantity))
#> 01/09/21 01/16/21 01/23/21 01/30/21 
#>     2.00     2.00     3.00     2.95

Created on 2024-04-13 with reprex v2.0.2

Consider running pre and post calculations with aggregate using transform:
aggregate(
  x = cbind(revenue, quantity) ~ date, 
  data = transform(df, revenue = price * quantity),
  FUN = sum
) |> transform(
  weighted_average = revenue / quantity
)
#       date revenue quantity weighted_average
# 1 01/09/21    30.0       15             2.00
# 2 01/16/21    30.0       15             2.00
# 3 01/23/21    15.0        5             3.00
# 4 01/30/21    29.5       10             2.95


There's weighted.mean() in base installation.
> by(df, df$date, \(x) {
+   with(x, data.frame(date=el(date), 
+                      price_weighted=weighted.mean(price, quantity/sum(quantity))))
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
             date price_weighted
01/09/21 01/09/21           2.00
01/16/21 01/16/21           2.00
01/23/21 01/23/21           3.00
01/30/21 01/30/21           2.95

